# react bundle analysis fails, source-map-explorer unable to map

Tags: reactjs, source-map-explorer

I am trying to analyze my react bundle size to see which dependencies are causing its relatively large size of >1MB.

I stumbled upon https://create-react-app.dev/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size/ and followed everything exactly as described.

However, when I run `npx source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'` I get `unable to map .../... bytes (5%)`.
After some googling, I found https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8430.

The "temporary fix" was to do `npx source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js' --only-mapped`  instead, but when I do that the output is completely blank and I also get a file not found in the browser when it tries to open the analysis.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it? Or are there better alternatives for analyzing the react bundle?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

this can be a better alternative.